# Second div inside static container div take up remaining height below a dynamic-height title

Tags: html, css

I have a div with two divs inside of it (one is the title and one is the content).  The container div's height must remain the same, and the title div's height contains text that is set in units of vw, so the number of lines of text will change depending on the users' screen, in addition to the height of the div.  I want the content div to fill the remaining height in the container without expanding it.  How would I go about doing this?

http://jsfiddle.net/3sjrv5rz/

```css
div.container{
   height:200px;
   width:200px;
}

div.title{
    font-size:4vw;
}

div.content{
    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="title">This is my title and it may be on multiple lines with different size screens</div>
    <div class="content">
        This is my content and will contain a Google Visualization graph.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The container div is not expanding, however the content will overflow it if is bigger in height than 200 -4vw title right ?

Comment: The container div is not expanding. It will remajn at 200px height no matter what. However, the content div is overflowing it if height is bigger that 200px - 4vw title right ?. You might put overflow:hidden on your container to prevent that overflow, however the content might get clipped. Maybe use some javascript to calculate the height of Title div after is loaded  and set content height properly ?

Comment: I was just wondering if there was something with only CSS that would solve this.  For my purposes, clipped content isn't acceptable, so I came up with a Javascript solution.

Comment: Well, I don't think CSS can do post-loading calculation based on variable measures. That's javascript task IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more thought, and thanks to Janx from Venezuela's comment, I decided to use a javascript solution.  This function works to resize the content div to whatever number of pixels remains.  I attach this to window.onresize and the thing resizes properly!

```js
function resizeTitles(){
 //1) Check the size of the titles
 //2) Check the size of the container div
 //3) Get remaining pixel height
 //4) Assign height to the flex div
 var titleHeight = document.getElementById("wind-title").clientHeight;
 var containerHeight = document.getElementById("wind-container").clientHeight;
 var remainingPixels = (containerHeight - titleHeight).toString();
 document.getElementById("wind-wrapper").style.height = remainingPixels.concat("px");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `overflow: scroll` for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/x0cLa1Lu/

Comment: I'm sorry-I should have added that one requirement is that the entire content div is always visible.  This would be a great solution if scroll bars were acceptable though!